# How to create a page through a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a gem which will create a page for your rails site say example.com/data and this page will show certain statistics about current rails installation say version etc.

Now I have created the gem using

```
bundle gem my_gem
```

but little unsure how to create a page through lib/my_gem.rb, can someone guide me here ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way I've done it in the past was to make a mountable Rails engine and mount that into your routes configuration. Here's a railscast on it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

Comment: Thanks, well doesn't this looks overkill ? as I just want one page to show few site stats.

Comment: True it may be a bit overkill. Alternatively, you could use Sinatra and mount it into your gem at a given route. That's what the sidekiq gem uses for statistics. Here is the source: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/web.rb